# Audio in Battlefield 4 open beta coming through speakers

Tags: audio-hardware, battlefield-4

I have joined the Battlefield 4 open beta and I am having some problems with audio. I am using a laptop to play, and the game's audio is coming through the main speakers rather than the headphones, despite the fact that I have the headphones plugged in. Audio from other applications come through the headphones as you would expect; it is only Battlefield 4 which fails to do so.

My audio config looks as follows:

[image: Audio configuration on my laptop.]

**EDIT**. I have run the following test. With my headphones plugged, I open up iTunes and start playing a song. As you would expect, it plays through the heaphones. Then I start up Battlefield 4. It takes a few minutes. As soon as I see the "loading level..." message, all the audio suddently switches from the headphones to the main speakers, including the music from iTunes. When I shut down Battlefield, sound goes back to the headphones. Isn't it odd?

Any ideas on how to route Battlefield 4 audio correctly through the headphones? Thank you.

Comment: Is it all BF4 sounds coming through the speakers, or is it some through both (i.e VOIP through headphones and sound effects through speakers?)

Comment: What is your default playback device in your sound settings in control panel? (Control panel -> hardware and sound -> manage audio devices) Is it your headphones or speakers?

Comment: @tombull89: Sound effects come through speakers, definitely. VOIP I don't know; I haven't seen (heard?) it working yet.

Comment: @3ventic: I have edited my question with a screenshot of my audio config. As you can see, the speakers/headphones are the default device, but the "communication headphones" are the default communications device, whatever that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. I have disabled the "Communication Headphones" and now it works. Don't ask me why, though.

Thanks for all the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see here is disable the speakers/headphones and set the communication headphones as default and set it as the only device that can be used, and see.

You can change it back once you are done playing, but at least you will enjoy your game.

Comment: No luck. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old thread but just in case others are having the same issue... here is what I did to get mine fixed:

1) In your taskbar, right click the speaker icon and click "PLAYBACK DEVICES".
2) Under the "PLAYBACK" and "RECORDING" tab make sure to select the device you want to use as DEFAULT (both default device and default communications).
3) go to http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/settings/voice/  and select the correct device. (It will save when you change the options via drop down.)

Good luck!